# what is the difference between cssSelector and ByCssSelector in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, findelement

what is the difference between By.cssSelector and By.ByCssSelector in the below code.

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("test")).click();
driver.findElement(By.ByCssSelector.id("")).click();

Comment: Where did you find `By.ByCssSelector.id()`

Answer (score 1):

`cssSelector` - static method of By Class.

`ByCssSelector` - static inner class of By Class.

`cssSelector` method internally creates `ByCssSelector` class.

Hence

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("test")).click();
```

can be written as

```
driver.findElement(new By.ByCssSelector("test")).click();
```

Both are same.

**Update:**

```
driver.findElement(By.ByCssSelector.id("test")).click();
```

Above statement is invalid since

- findElement expects `By` object and `new` keyword is missing.
- We have to pass css selector value when calling `ByCssSelector` since it has
  parameterized constructor which takes cssselector value.
- `ByCssSelector` inner class doesn't have id method to invoke.

Comment: You didn't address `By.ByCssSelector.id()` :)

Comment: That statement doesnt make sense. We have to pass css selector value when calling `ByCssSelector` since it has parameterized constructor which takes cssselector value.